# Full Body Workout Routine for late novice

Tags: workout-routines, strength, bodybuilding, hypertrophy

Hey guys i have a question. I am a late novice and other Routines like strong lifts, ICF, starting strength doesnt suit me because they lack on volume, take too long, hit fast the stalling wall etc ...What do you think about this workout Routines? Its full body 3 times a week:

Day 1 : Strength Legs/Back , hypertrophy Push

Squats 4x4-5
Incline benchpress 5x8
Power Rows 4x5
Closegrip Benchpress 2x10
Bicepscurls 2x10

Day 2 : Strength Push , hypertrophy legs/Back

Benchpress 4x4 
Legpress/squats 4x8
Pull ups 3x5 ramped sets
Military Press 4x6
RDL 2x12

Day 3 : Deadlift , Light Accessories

Deadlift 1x5 2x7
Benchpress 3x10
Pendlay Row/lat pulldown 3x10
Shrugs 2x10

Goal is too become stronger and more muscular

Comment: pick normal program, for example [Bridge](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/the-bridge/) from "Barbell Medicine"

Answer (score 5):

In general you're not going to be to outsmart a proven program with whatever you put together yourself. If you could develop a training program that worked better than [Starting Strength](https://startingstrength.com/about) or [Strong Lifts](https://stronglifts.com/5x5/) then everyone would adopt it.

You're making the (probably incorrect) assumption that the program you've outlined above will get you more results in less time. It's possible, but you really need to ask yourself if you feel that you've come up with something better or if it's more about impatience.

I hope that's not too rough of an answer, but you'd be much better off sticking with an established training program than trying to DIY it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if you stick to some proven method like German Volume Training. It's similar to what your program looks like, but it's much more tested and proven to work. Also, it has a very high volume and takes relatively short time to complete. It's also ideal for hypertrophy, which is one of your main goals.

https://www.strengthsensei.com/german-volume-training-introduction/
Here's the link to a GVT article.

Comment: German Volume Training has been proven to be substantially worse than doing half the volume of it! http://suppversity.blogspot.com/2016/12/gvt-too-much-volume-only-trunk-legs-and.html

Comment: @DavidScarlett - Got any other sources for this? A single n=19 study seems very thin if they really want to debunk the GVT method, and say it's been "proven" to be worse. Also, this article mentions virtually nothing about how the study was carried out. Also, since it's just posted on a blog, it's hard to tell if it's been peer reviewed.

Comment: All I have besides that is a link to the study, but only the abstract is available for free: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27941492

Answer (score 0):

I liked doing [531](https://jimwendler.com/collections/books-programs/products/5-3-1-second-edition-hard-copy) for a little under a year, after being detrained for over a decade.  It does not have high volume, but I found that it worked better for me than Starting Strength and Strong Lifts.  Starting Strength was awesome for form on the compound lifts, but I liked 531 with assistance lifts better, and the progressions worked way better for me.

I would hit regular PR's and built a solid strength base before moving to more of a hypertrophy focus.  Now I'm just doing a PUSH/PULL/LEGS split with compound lifts integrated, but I think using some kind of proven program instead of rolling your own is good when starting out.  Then you save time by not making the mistakes the other people may have already worked through over the years before they had a known program.

So if you did something like 531, you can always incorporate the assistance lifts you want and like, but still have a solid core to build off of.  Just don't go crazy on the amount of assistance you lifts you add.

Also the Kindle ebook edition is cheaper and there are several apps that work for 531 to track what you are doing.

Comment: 531 has insane little volume. I don't say that's not working for you, but there are better programs out there.

Comment: It does have lower volume, but to me that adds the advantage of adding more to the assistance lifts without overtraining.  I'm not doing it now, but my comparison was to other 'starter' programs and not all programs in general.